# System Tray Icons Stretching on Mouse Hovering

Tags: icons, resize, system-tray

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 with Gnome 3.36.3. I don't know why, almost every time I hover with my mouse over the system tray icons, they will resize automatically to fit the tray. I believe this must be a Gnome Shell bug, but I don't know how to fix it. Any clues? Thanks!